# Using a map within a map conditionally rendering data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, array.prototype.map

Im currently mapping through some local JSON data and trying to render out each object depending on its name,

currently, I've mapped over it displaying each name now conditionally checking and mapping each ones specific data , just trying to get the correct syntax here.

```
import menu from "./data/menudata";

const MenuBar = () => {
  return (
    <MenuContainer>
      {menu.children.map((outerMap, i) => (
        <Dropdown>
          <DropBtn key={i}>
            <h2>{outerMap.name}</h2>
          </DropBtn>
          <DropdownContent>
           {outerMap.name === 'Account' && (
           
              {menu.firstchild.map((innerMap, i) => 
                <li>{firstchild.name}</li>
                )}
           )
           } 
          </DropdownContent>
        </Dropdown>
      ))}
    </MenuContainer>
  );
};

export default MenuBar;
```

The innermap is where I cannot get it to compile, here is a snippet of the JSON code aswell,

```
"name": "menu",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Account",
      "firstchild": [
        {
          "name": "Preference"
        },
        {
          "name": "Contact"
        },
        {
          "name": "Manage"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Design",
      "secondchild": [
        {
          "name": "Theme"
        },
        {
          "name": "Gallery"
        },
        {
          "name": "Template"
        }
      ]
    },
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `outerMap.firstchild` not `menu.firstchild`.

`{outerMap.name === 'Account' && outerMap.firstchild.map((innerMap, i) => ...)}`

Comment: cheers basically just didn't need the second set of curly braces in the conditional statement